# What's the difference between 一下子，一刹那，and 一时

Tags: usage, difference

I know the usage of 一下子 but I don't really understand about 一刹那 and 一时

Answer (score 3, accepted):

一下子 = all of a sudden. e.g.  **一下子**不見了  gone **all of a sudden**

刹那 is a Buddhism term for a time unit. In one flick of a finger, 60 刹那 would pass

一刹那 = a very brief moment. e.g. 在**一刹那**間 (in **the blink of an eye**) = almost instantly

一时 = at the moment/ at the time. e.g. 一时找不到人选 (Can't find a candidate **at the moment**/ **at the time**)

*一瞬間 (in the time of one glance), 一息間 (in the time of one breath) and 瞬息間 are the terms similar to 刹那間 (in the time of a 刹那). They can all be translated as "in the blink of an eye"*

Comment: Which's the most used in daily?

Comment: "all of a sudden", "in a blink of an eye", and "at the moment" are used in different contexts. They are not interchangeable

Comment: @sinwi 一下(子)、一時 are more popular and orally than 刹那、 瞬間。